# How to submit button clicked, everything displayed in React

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, axios, fetch

I have a dropdown list of the room number, what I want is that when the user chooses the room number and clicks the "Get room" button, the information of this room will display the table information in case this room is on my database, otherwise, we display "This room does not have a device installed" and "add device button"

[image: Dashboard]

My code below displays the table before the button on click. I want the table displayed after the button on clicked and confirmed the device is on the database. And also how can attach the room number chosen in table Room x as well?
My frontend code:

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        uploadedFileCloudinaryUrl: '',
        x:0,
        y:0,
        roomID: '',
        data: []
      };
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {    
    this.setState({roomID: event.target.value}); 
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    console.log('Room chosen is: ' + this.state.roomID);
    event.preventDefault();

    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/room_selected`)
      .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
      })
      .then(function(){

      });
      
  
    }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/information').
      then(response => response.json()).
      then(findresponse => {
        this.setState({
          data: [findresponse]
        });
      })
  }
render(){
return(
<FormGroup controlId="formControlsSelect">
      <ControlLabel>Select Room Number</ControlLabel>
      <FormControl componentClass="select" placeholder="select" value={this.state.room} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
      </FormControl>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <div style={{display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}}>
      <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit} class="btn btn-secondary" justify-content="center">Get Room</Button></div>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <div>
        {
          this.state.data.map((dynamicData, Key) => {
            let keys = Object.keys(dynamicData);
            let d = dynamicData;
            return keys.map(data => {
              return (
                <div className="content" style={{border: '1px solid black'}}>
                      
                <h3>Room {this.state.room} </h3>
                <p>IllumW: {dynamicData[data].illumW}</p>
                <p>Temperature: {dynamicData[data].temperature}</p>
                <p>Hummidity: {dynamicData[data].humidity}</p>
                
                </div>
              );
            });
          })
          
        }
      </div>

    </FormGroup>    
)
})
}
```

My backend code is:

```
app.get('/room_selected', function (req, res){
    var client = 'a@gmail.com';
    var room = 'Room 1';

    var query = connection.query ('SELECT ClientID FROM clientDevices WHERE DeviceName = ?', [room]);
    if (client == query[0].ClientID){
        res.send('Success');
    } else {
        res.send('The selected room does not have a device attached');      
    }

});

app.get('/information', function(req, res){
    var room = 'Room 1';
    var query = connection.query ( 'SELECT keyvalueTB.illumW, keyvalueTB.temperature, keyvalueTB.humidity FROM keyvalueTB INNER JOIN clientDevices ON clientDevices.DevEUI = keyvalueTB.DevEUI WHERE clientDevices.DeviceName = "Room 1" ORDER BY keyvalueTB.Timestmp desc limit 1 ');
    console.log(query);
    res.send(query);

});

console.log("Listening on port 8080");
app.listen(8080);
```

Can someone stop by for help? I am really appreciated that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can't see you send the ID of the room anywhere in the axios post? If I'm not mistaken your room_selected is just a general url without any indication on which room to get.

Comment: Room ID will send when the user choose a room in dropdown list